# (Flutter/Dart) How to fix displaying numbers from list with [ ]

Tags: list, flutter, csv, dart, display

So when getting this list from a csv file, it displays in the table as follows:

[1] [2] [3] [4]

I want just the numbers to get displayed, the file they're stored in does not contain the [] just the numbers.
This is the code to fetch it:

```
final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/Prod.csv");
List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
print(csvTable);
```

The print shows the following:
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]

Fyi there's another file where the numbers are displayed just fine and the list is stored and fetched the same way so I'm not sure where's the problem here.

Comment: `convert` _returns a List (rows) of Lists (columns)_ , so presumably it's interpreting your file as 4 rows of one column each.

Comment: @RichardHeap so what should I replace it with?

Comment: We'd have to see what's in your CSV - including all the control characters.

Comment: 1
1
100.0
1
1
1

Comment: That's what's in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> listOfInt = [];
List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
for ( var row in csvTable){
 for {var num in row){
   listOfInt.add(num);
 }
}
```